# Ignore last string in URL after the last slash

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

for example: when a user types in `www.website.com/site/blue`, I want them to go to `www.website.com/site/index.php` in the web browser. The reason for this is that I want to use php to grab blue from the URL and place it in `www.website.com/site/index.php`

So when someone types in `www.website.com/site/blue` ... they should see `"Hello blue!!!"` in `www.website.com/site/index.php`

Comment: Have you tried anything, or are you hoping someone will right the code for you.

Comment: i tried with no luck. not even sure where to get started. but i was able to extract the last string from the url.. sorry

Comment: You need to look into URL rewriting / Apache's mod_rewrite (if you're using Apache)

Comment: looking into it now... not sure where to begin..

Comment: htaccess can solve this. Try searching the right config for htaccess.

Comment: yup looking into now... im no expert.. might take a while ill let u guys know how it goes

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need to use an htaccess file and Apache's mod_rewrite. If you are allowed to do this on your server, make a file called `.htaccess` in the `site` directory.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?color=$1
```

That will rewrite every request as a query string to `index.php` for you to parse.

Comment: Note sure if thats the right rewrite syntax but rewrite is def the way to go.

Comment: I know it looks funny, but I just double checked the syntax. Unless I'm just really missing something, that is right.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can split the page URL at the "/" and it will give you an array of parts of the URL. The last of these parts will be "blue" in your example. Try something like the following:

```
var parts = document.URL.split("/");
var foo = parts.pop();
var url = parts.join("/") + "/index.php";
window.location.href = url;
```

And then the variable `foo` is the variable "blue" that you're looking for.

Comment: looks like window.location.href = url; is what i was looking for. let me test....

Answer (score 0):

try this htaccess config:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: this works but... when i type in something likehttp://trinoweb.com/site/blue ...it breaks the page... but when i type in http://trinoweb.com/site/ it looks fine...

Comment: put it in your system folder and try requesting www.website.com/site/blue, it should execute the www.website.com/site/index.php. All you have to do now is to manipulate the url in index.php to get the desired output "Hello blue!!!!"

Comment: what do you mean breaks the page? is the page not found or the css is not working? If the css is not working, please use absolute URLS in your images and other external files.

Comment: @user1032854 I am happy you got it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12008/discussion-between-user1032854-and-rechie)

Comment: please use absolute url for you external files.

Comment: please check if your CSS files are loaded. Firebug can help you.

Comment: hey rechie... i think RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA] rewrites only the root directory??? i need www.example.com/site/blue to go to www.example.com/site/index.php ....

Comment: i dont think this is going to work. i will test again tomorrow. thanks for all your help.