# Configure htaccess file to ignore last directory after slash and redirect with variable

Tags: php, .htaccess

for example:

www.site.com/your/blue

will redirect to... www.site.com/your/index.php?=blue

right now when someone types in www.site.com/your/blue it throws an error saying page does not exist.
can anyone help me with this? thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you give us some code hints? Without some code, we can't help you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ignore last string in URL after the last slash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843740/ignore-last-string-in-url-after-the-last-slash)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mod rewrite has to be used for this kind of redirects:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/?$ $1/index.php?page=$2 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This regex ensures a clean url is being passed to the site and works with or without a ending slash.

NB: Parameters passed to PHP need to have a name so I added page=

**If you want it to work without any restriction (spaces will work)**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1/index.php?page=$2 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: hey it doesnt work with space on everything after last slash for example www.site.com/your/one two three .... it shows up as www.site.com/your/one%20two%20three and gives me a page not found error

Comment: Mine should work with spaces... just sayin'

Comment: Maybe it doesn't work with spaces, but my definition of a clean url doesn't include having spaces in it. That kind of url (www.site.com/your/one%20two%20three) is not that readable to the human eye, so I prefer to use underscores or hyphens to separate words in a folder name.

Comment: but can you make it catch spaces and %20 as well so it redirects with it???

Comment: ur second edit works... thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Use [mod rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html):

```
RewriteEngine On   
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/$ $1/index.php?p=$2 [L]
```

(I added `p` as name of the query string, because it can't be empty)

---

Additionally, you can add the following lines of code between `RewriteEngine On` and the rewrite rule to make sure there's a trailing slash (which is recommended):

```
# Add trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.site.com/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I would write `(.*)/(.*)/?`, otherwise only site.com/your/blue/ will be redirected, but not site.com/your/blue

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.trinoweb.com/$1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/$ $1/index.php?p=$2 [L]

Comment: nevermind.... it doesnt work.. just gives me a page not found error :(